Concatenating an object for a list
I'm working with Python. I'm trying to prefill a list with a loop. I already got the correct values to write to the list with a slew of individual commands following the creation of each Entry box. But a loop would be more efficient.
I'm doing this:
WOBOXES = []

for i in range(117):
    if i == 0:
        WOBOXES.append("<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry>")
    if i > 0:
        a = i + 1
        b = "<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry" + str(a) + ">"
        WOBOXES.append(b)

This works, sort of. The output is . . .
'<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry>', '<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry2>', '<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry3>', etc.

But the output needs to be . . .
<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry>, <tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry2>, <tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry3>, etc.

When I try to do it without the "" around the text, I get an error. For the objects in the list to function as intended, they need to be written to the list without the "" so they aren't in the list with '' around the text.
Any ideas how I can get them written so they'll go to the list correctly, and without single or double quotes?
Edit:
I have thirteen rows of nine entry boxes each. These are to accommodate a vendor, purchased part number, displayed part number, description of the part or service, quantity, part cost, retail price, labor hours, and labor dollars.
To the left of each line is a series of three buttons. One to delete the line, one to shift the line down by one, and one to shift the line up by one.
To make the delete button work, I have to copy the values from the line below it, delete the row that's being deleted, rewrite the values from the line below into the current line, and then repeat the process down to the last row. That's a lot of variables and a lot of work.
A simple loop dealt with the tedium nicely. But it requires a dictionary and a list. The dictionary stores the values, and the list has the Entry boxes so the loop knows where to write the dictionary values.
The current version, which does work, I create an Entry box, and then append it to the list. It writes to the list without the single quotes ''. When I try to prewrite the Entry boxes to the list, they are written with the single quotes.
I hope this sufficiently answers why I'm trying to do this.
The same process will simultaneously aid in the functions for the other buttons. I only have to set it up once.
Edit:
An example of the long code, as requested.
#Work Order Entry Box Dictionary
IE = {}
for i in range(117):
    IE[i] = None #This presets all my keys with blank values.

#Work Order Box List
WOBOXES = [] #Empty list. Would like to prefill it with a loop.

def vendor_1(event):
    IE[0] = vendbox1.get() #This writes the box data to the dictionary as I type.
vendfrm1 = tkinter.Frame(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", width=58, height=25, borderwidth=2, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN) #This is for visual effect, lacking a margin option in an Entry box.
vendfrm1.place(x=144, y=110)
vendbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=8, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
vendbox1.place(x=150, y=114)
WOBOXES.append(vendbox1) #This adds the box to the list.
vendbox1.bind("<KeyRelease>", vendor_1) #This runs the function to write the Entry box data to the dictionary.

def on_enter(event):
    DelBut1.config(bg="#333537")
def on_leave(event):
    DelBut1.config(bg="#292d2e") #These two functions are hover highlights.

#This is the code for the first delete button to delete the current row and move all the others up.
def del1(event):
    for i in range(108):
        a = i + 9
        IE[i] = IE[a]
        IE[a] = None
    for j in range(117):
        textbox = WOBOXES[j]
        textbox.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    for k in range(117):
        if IE[k] == None:
            continue
        textbox = WOBOXES[k]
        textbox.insert(0, IE[k])

#This is the button and its bindings.
DelBut1 = tkinter.Button(master=wofrm, width=3, bg="#292d2e", fg="#962d10", text="X", relief=tkinter.FLAT, takefocus=False)
DelBut1.place(x=46, y=110)
DelBut1.bind("<Enter>", on_enter)
DelBut1.bind("<Leave>", on_leave)
DelBut1.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", del1)

This shows one Entry box, one delete button, and the loop code to run the row delete. There are 116 more Entry boxes and 12 more delete buttons. But this should adequately show what I'm doing.

What language is this, Python? Please [edit] to add the tag for it. While you're there, please write a more descriptive title (see [ask] for tips) and make a [mre] including less code (e.g. do range(3) for the sake of a smaller example) and complete output instead of using "etc."

If this is Python, here's a hint: What type are the values you're writing to the list? What type are they supposed to be?

This works, sort of. The output is . . . What does "the output" mean?  Do you mean something like print(WOBOXES) ?  Please show us the exact code which produces that output.

@wjandrea, I'm still new at this. Hints aren't going to help at this stage. I learn fast. But the hint leaves me as clueless as I was when I wrote the question. Could you please elaborate so I can learn from your advice and experience?

Normally I don't reply to rude comments, but I just want to point out I gave you three things to fix. The language is the most pressing, but the title is the most important for question quality, and the current title doesn't really describe the problem. You're not actually concatenating anything in this code.

@John Gordon, yes, I used a print(WOBOXES) to check the contents of the list. But I used it solely for that purpose, to find out what was being written to the list. The long version was like this: vendbox1 = tkinter.Entry(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=8, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
vendbox1.place(x=150, y=114)
WOBOXES.append(vendbox1)

@AFrazier I'm trying to point you in the right direction. All you have to do is answer the questions: "What type are the values you're writing to the list? What type are they supposed to be?" If you don't know what I mean by "type" or something, just ask.

@wjandrea, this: b = "<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry" + str(a) + ">" is a concatenation. Or am I misunderstanding the definition of concatenation?

@AFrazier My mistake, that is a concatenation. But it isn't really relevant to the problem since you could just as easily use f-strings (b = f"<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry {a}>") or templates.

I'm struggling to understand what you actually want.  Do you want a list of strings, or do you want a list of tkinter.Entry objects?

@John Gordon, I want a list of tkinter.Entry objects. I already built it the long way. It works as desired. But it takes up a lot of space, and I know it can be done with a loop. I just don't know the correct way to format the concatenated string to get it to write to the list in the correct format, that being without the single '' quotes.

I want a list of tkinter.Entry objects Then why are you messing about with a list of strings?  I am very confused.  What is the purpose of the strings?

@MatBailie, I only printed it to the console to check the values that were written. It's not part of the normal code. I needed to know that it was writing it to the list correctly. And it's not. So, I'm trying to figure out how to get it to write correctly.

@wjandrea, I just tried b = f"<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry {a}>". It gives the same result. '' around the string.

See the edit for the purpose.

Show us the long winded working code ("with a slew of individual commands") for creating a list of three elements. Then we'll see what you want. (Your description is clearly not working, maybe a demonstration will work instead.)

I think you are seeing the difference between printing a string and printing a list that happens to contain strings.  If you print a string directly, the quotes do not appear in the output.  If you print a list, then you will see the native representation of each item in the list, and the native representation of a string includes the quote marks.

@MatBailie, okay. One sec. I'll add another edit.

Even if you can print the string '<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry>' as you want without the quotes, what is the purpose?  It's still just a string.  It is not an actual tkinter.Entry object, which you said you wanted.

Don't describe the working code, include the actual working code in the question...

If those of you responsible don't mind saying, why are you down voting this question? I'm new at this. I'm trying to learn. I asked a sincere question, and for a valid reason. I unintentionally neglected a piece of information, which I corrected. Other than that, what's wrong with my question that it's being treated with so much scorn and contempt? At the end of the day, after answering so many questions about my question, the same question still remains. How can I get the code into the list via a loop without quotes so it will function properly?

@MatBailie, I just did. It's in there in the edit.

Do you understand that the string "<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry>" is NOT an actual tkinter.Entry object?  I've asked several times why you insist on creating strings, and have not gotten an answer...

My guess is that the OP did it manually, without a loop, printed the resulting list, and is trying to reproduce the string representation of the list. But, no, the OP doesn't yet understand that the string representation of the objects doesn't reference or create objects.

@John Gordon and MatBailie, yes, I'm trying to reproduce the items in the list. I created it as shown in the second edit. I tested it. It works. I printed the list to the console to see what the entry in the list actually was. So, I'm trying to manually enter the same thing with a loop instead of having 117 individual appends. And I DO understand that a string won't work. That's why I'm trying to solve the problem of removing the quotes. It's going to the list as a string in the loop. It gives me errors if I do it without the quotes. If I can get them in there without them, they'll work.

Instead of saying vague things like "It gives me errors if I do it without the quotes", please show us the actual code and the actual error.

"If I can get them in there without them, they'll work." - No, they won't. That's absolutely incorrect. The strings you see are representations of objects after they've been created (such as by using vendbox = tkinter.Entry(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=8, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)). You can't use those strings to create or reference the objects. You are working to numerous false assumptions. Please read xyproblem.info

What's wrong with instantiating the objects in a loop? As per the answer below.

@John Gordon. I appreciate that you're trying to help. I showed explicitly what the problem was. I gave the code I used. I showed what result I was getting. And I showed what result I wanted to get. When I try to manually create the list entry in the loop, I can only do it as a string that results in single quotes around the list item: '<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry>' But the way it needs to be, so it's not a string, is to be without the single quotes: <tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry> This is how the items are actually listed when I create them the long way.

@MatBailie, there's nothing wrong with the solution you gave, and I'm thankful and appreciative for your input. I'm digesting it. I'm still new at Python. My hat's off to you for being the only one to actually attempt a real answer rather than simply condescending to me as though every beginner should just know this stuff. The difficulty I'm contemplating is that the Entry boxes are different sizes, with different variables. It would take some thought to create a loop that can map them all out correctly.

<tkinter.Entry object .!frame3.!entry> That is how an Entry object is displayed when it is printed, but that is not the correct syntax to create one.

@John Gordon. Understood. I gave up. Someone closed the question, and only one person actually offered a solution to the question rather than questioning or criticizing me, and that solution isn't compatible with the complexity of the other functions I have to accomplish. So, I'm just doing it the long way.

for y in range(13):
   for x in range(9):
      vendbox = tkinter.Entry(master=wofrm, bg="#b2b4b7", fg="#000000", width=8, borderwidth=0, relief=tkinter.FLAT)
      vendbox.place(x=150 + x*something, y=114 + y*something) 
      WOBOXES.append(vendbox) #This adds the box to the list.
      vendbox.bind("<KeyRelease>", vendor_1) #This runs the function to write the Entry box data to the dictionary.

x*something and y*something need to be calculations for whatever x, y position each box should be at
